# pidgin install conflicts with libpurple old and new?

Tags: installation, yum

```
 package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/ur/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
  file /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/pidgin.mo from install of libpurple-2.6.6-5.el5_5.i386 conflicts with file from package libpurple-2.7.11-0.el5.x86_64
```

anyone have the same problem??

thanks

Adam ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mixing architectures

why not

```
rpm -e libpurple pidgin
```

first?

Comment: ok after that? what should i do ?

Comment: Jamespo's command uninstalls both libpurple and pidgin.  After that, you should reinstall them.  From the same repository.

Comment: wew now thats what i call fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu, its 6 hours dealing with yum erase thing and uninstall lol. thanks. james . i really apriciet it.